# Type-casting issue

Tags: sqlite

In the following query, the answer of 1/2 is always zero while it should be 0.5. Can you please tell me how to convert the two int columns into float/double?

```
SELECT 1/2, total, sb_ondate, likes
  FROM (
      SELECT sb_ondate, COUNT(*) AS total,
             STRFTIME("%w",sb_ondate) AS weekDay,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN sb_reaction = 'like' THEN sb_id END) AS likes
        FROM diet
    GROUP BY weekDay) AS f;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Cast` one of the two divisors as a `real`:

```
SELECT 1 / CAST(2 AS REAL),...
```

Sample interactive Python session:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c.execute("create table t (a int,b int);")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f9b0e9539d0>
>>> c.execute("insert into t values (1,2)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f9b0e953ad8>
>>> conn.execute("select a / cast(b as real) from t").fetchone()
(0.5,)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a "SIR" LOL

Comment: Why _unfortunately_? Embrace that Y chromosome, my friend ;D

Answer (score 6):

Add `.0` to one of the constants:

```
sqlite> select 1/2;
1/2
----------
0
sqlite> select 1.0/2;
1.0/2
----------
0.5
```